# javascript function isn't called in a XSLT document with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

With the help of a onchange event on a drop-down menu, I make that only the paragraph relevant to a category are displayed. It works on FF and Opera, but on IE 7 and IE 8 there is no change when selecting a new option on the drop-down menu, and only the default paragraph are displayed.

The javascript code does work as intended when inserted in a html document (only the wanted paragraph are displayed).

XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>help center</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        function showHide(selection) {
        var f = selection.form;
        var opt = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
        var divArray = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i=0; i<divArray.length; i++){
            if(divArray[i].className == "first1"){
                if(opt=="first1"){
                    divArray[i].style.display = "";
                }else{
                    divArray[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            if(divArray[i].className == "second2"){
                if(opt=="second2"){
                    divArray[i].style.display = "";
                }else{
                    divArray[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            if(divArray[i].className == "third3"){
                if(opt=="third3"){
                    divArray[i].style.display = "";
                }else{
                    divArray[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }]]>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:arial;">
        <div id="header" style="background-color:#fffacd;">
        <h1>Help Center</h1>
        <noscript>
            <p><font color="red"><b>The Help Center require javascript for optimal use.</b></font></p>
        </noscript>
        <form>
            <select name="release" onchange="return showHide(this);">
                <option value="first1" selected="selected">first1</option>
                <option value="second2">second2</option>
                <option value="third3">third3</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <xsl:for-each select="sections/section">
            <h2><xsl:value-of select='name'/></h2>    

            <div class="first1">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="instructions/instruction[releases//release='first1']">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="content"/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="second2" style="display:none;">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="instructions/instruction[releases//release='second2']">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="content"/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="third3" style="display:none;">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="instructions/instruction[releases//release='third3']">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="content"/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>

    <hr />

    <p style="font-size:10px;background-color:#fffacd;"><br /></p>

    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="help.xsl"?>
<sections>
<section>
<name>First Section</name>
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
            <release>second2</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Do first step
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Do auxiallary step 1.5
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>second2</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            no auxilliary step needed
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
            <release>second2</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Do second test.
            This step is important.
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>third3</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Do the first advanced step.
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>third3</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Do the second advanced step.
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
            <release>second2</release>
            <release>third3</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            This is a common step.
        </content>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</section>
<section>
<name>Second section</name>
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
            <release>second2</release>
            <release>third3</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            This is some &lt;foo&gt;, where
            &lt;bar&gt; is important.
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>first1</release>
            <release>second2</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Foobar.
        </content>
    </instruction>
    <instruction>
        <releases>
            <release>third3</release>
        </releases>
        <content>
            Barfoo.
        </content>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</section>
</sections>
```

Comment: Do you really think that is an XSLT problem? Your script is inside the result of an XSLT transformation so first thing to check is whether it works with IE in a static HTML document that is not generated by XSLT. If you think the problem is related to XSLT then please also provide an XML input sample you apply that XSLT to, to allow us the reproduce the problem. Or post a URL where we can visit the problem. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: You've got a good point. I've tested in a static HTML, like you advised. Unfortunately, it confirmed what I thought, as it works on a static HTML, whichever is the browser used.

I've added the XML Imput (at least I think it is what you meant.

Comment: As the accepted answer of @Martin-Honnen shows, this is not an XSLT problem at all. You could be using a static XHTML document and getting the same error. This fact clearly points out that this question hardly qualifies as xslt question. It is very slightly xslt-related and it is most of all browser-related.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev or anyone who could answer: Maybe it would make sence that I add the xhtml tag to it and modify the question accordingly, so people finding this question could better identify the problem, what do you think?

Comment: I think that the current two tags are most adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your sample with IE 8 on Windows XP, it pops up its error dialog with a syntax error. I think the reason/explanation is that your XSLT outputs an X(HT)ML document, not a HTML document. Mozilla and other browsers support that but with IE the problem is that its XSLT processor serializes the XSLT result according to XML rules and IE then tries to parse that with its HTML parser. So for the script code the HTML parser and the JScript engine of IE tries to parse `for (var i=0; i&lt;divArray.length; i++){` and that results in the syntax error. That way the complete script block is not parsed successfully and the function you want to use in the onchange handler is not defined.
I suggest you fix the problem by avoiding XHTML completely and simply use XSLT (1.0) for what it can do best, namely output HTML. So drop the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from your HTML root element, that way the code works without problems.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the main problem I had with IE. :)
I have two other minor issues, but I don't know it if is worth opening a new question yet. Time for a bit of investigation :)